# How to query results considering missing keys or matching values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

So, I have an object called audience. This object may contain a number of keys like age, gender, job_role, etc.

Something like this:

```
"audience": {
        "gender": [
          "Male",
          "Female"
        ],
        "household_income": [
          "<$25,000",
          "$25,001-$50,000",
          "$50,001-$100,000"
        ]
      }
```

And I want to query something like "where audience.gender = 'Male' or audience.gender does not exist". I'm new to elasticsearch so I'm quite confused as to how can I achieve this.

Comment: is the field gender actually an array in your documents? it seems a bit odd to me, but it is important to know in order to proivde an correct query as answer.

Comment: Yea, it is an array. The code sample I provided was taken out of one of my documents. Why do you think it is odd? If you know any better way to structure this, I'd like to know. I just structured it like this because I thought it would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple match query for that:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "audience.gender": "Male" 
    }
  }
}
```

In order to negate the same search query use a bool query instead with `must_not`

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "match": {
                    "audience.gender": "Male"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See the docs on arrays [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html)

And on Bool queries [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

If your list entries are actual obj. have a look at the [nested fieldtype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)